# String index out of range even though the string is limited

Tags: java, string

I am a student and I am learning Java.I recently got a question which said I had to find the largest word in a given string..I wrote a code but it is giving me an error that string index is out of bounds even though I limited it to the length of the string..Can someone help me with the code..Please use simple language(I am not an expert)

### Code

```
import java.util.*;
class word
{
    void def()
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the string");
        String s1=sc.nextLine();
        int length=s1.length();
        length++; //My name
        int j=0;  //0123456
        int word=0;
        int findex=0; 
        int lindex=0;
        int lword=0;
        for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
        {

            if(s1.charAt(i)==' ' && j==0)
            {
                lword=i;
                findex=0;
                lindex=i;
                j=i;
            }
            else if(s1.charAt(i)==' ')
            {
                if(i-j-1>lword)
                {
                    findex=j;
                    lindex=i;
                    lword=i-j-1;
                }
                j=i;
            }
            else if(i==length-1)
            {
                if(i-j-1>lword)
                {
                    findex=j;
                    lindex=i;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Largest word is:"+s1.substring(findex,lindex+1));
} 
}
```

Comment: Oh,didn't know that,sorry

Answer (score 1):

By doing `length++` you make sure that your `length` variable will be larger then the actual string length. at the last loop step there will be no char at `s1.charAt(i)`

Just remove the line with `length++`

Comment: Ohh,didn't notice that..Thank you very much :D..will mark you as answer in 8 minutes